# Using std::any error in header file - use of undeclared identifier 'any'

Tags: c++, std

I'm using `std::any`, which works well in cpp file, but error errors when used in header file. The C++ document doesn't state `any` could be only used in cpp files.

Example code
test.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <any>

using namespace std;

typedef map<string, any> any_map;    // error: use of undeclared identifier 'any'
```

**Environment** :
Clang12, C++17

Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice?rq=1

Comment: If you prefix all types with `std::` namespace like `typedef std::map<std::string, std::any> any_map;` does it solve the issue?

Comment: There is no difference between cpp and header files as far as the compiler is concerned, so your issue is caused by something else you haven't shown here. I'm guessing you didn't actually compile as c++17.

Comment: compile using `std=c++17`  flag.

Comment: thanks all.  With ```std::any```, it works in my test code.  CMake prompts it's using C++17.